# Is it possible to make edge loops on a flat surface with a modifier?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

Like, you can make edge loops on 3D objects with a bevel modifier with 2 segments and a 1.00 profile. Is there a way to also do this on the edge of a plane?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Mirror along X and Y + Bisect. Add a bevel modifier.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, it only bevels the inside edges. Also, the plane itself was just an example. What I want to use this for wont be symetrical.
Edit: Ahh I see, I think your's is also bevelling the inside edges, just big enough to look like the outside

Comment: Yes, it doesn't bevel from the outside, but from the inside edges created with the mirror modifier. Feel free to edit your question to be more specific, otherwise it might prove difficult to give you the answer you look for